# How i can insert plugin actions in the layout, on CAKEPHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins

i have a plugin 'contact'; i wanna set it on the layout page.
i used this code in layout page:

```
<?php $this->requestAction(array('plugin'=>'contact','controller'=>'mails','action'=>'index'),array('return'=>true)); ?>
```

But it doesn't work. Thank u

Comment: What do you mean by 'setting' a plugin on the 'layout' page? Do you want to call the index action of the mails controller in another controller action?

Because requestAction() method is a controller method and should be used only in your controller, not in a view layout file.

Comment: first i used "set" not "setting", and sec : for example in my Plugin/contact/mails/index.ctp i have this "Hi", i want to call this action (index) in the layout page. this what i mean

Comment: Yes, I converted 'set' into past tense, sorry. Which layout page are you exactly referring to? View/Layouts/default.ctp?

Comment: Yes, exactly. do u have any solution for that ? :)